# Output in PortAudio

Tags: c++, c, output, portaudio

I am trying to learn PortAudio, I am following the tutorials in *doc/src/tutorials*, this is the code in *writing_a_callback.dox*:

```
typedef struct
{
    float left_phase;
    float right_phase;
}   
paTestData;

/* This routine will be called by the PortAudio engine when audio is needed.
** It may called at interrupt level on some machines so don't do anything
** that could mess up the system like calling malloc() or free().
*/ 
static int patestCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                           unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                           const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                           PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                           void *userData )
{
    /* Cast data passed through stream to our structure. */
    paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData; 
    float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;
    unsigned int i;
    (void) inputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warning. */
    
    for( i=0; i<framesPerBuffer; i++ )
    {
        *out++ = data->left_phase;  /* left */
        *out++ = data->right_phase;  /* right */

        /* Generate simple sawtooth phaser that ranges between -1.0 and 1.0. */
        data->left_phase += 0.01f;
        /* When signal reaches top, drop back down. */
        if( data->left_phase >= 1.0f ) data->left_phase -= 2.0f;

        /* higher pitch so we can distinguish left and right. */
        data->right_phase += 0.03f;
        if( data->right_phase >= 1.0f ) data->right_phase -= 2.0f;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine, but I have a few questions:

1. I have a `struct` with 2 `float` variables, but how does PortAudio know which is for the left speaker and which for the right
2. In this example, what am I passing to the output buffer, frequency, volume or something else, and how can I tell PortAudio about the others, for example, if I am passing frequency then how can I tell it to adjust the volume

Probably I am missing something but... I don't know

---

Any attempt to help is appreciated

Comment: The struct `paTestData` is used to help generate the PCM output signal stored in `out`. It is not the signal itself. In a stereo PCM stream the left channel are the even samples (0,2,4) and the right channel are the odd samples (1,3,5). Frequency and amplitude are characteristics of the waveform, not parameters passed as variables. In the example frequency is determined by the size of the steps (`left_phase += 0.01` and `right_phase += 0.03`). Amplitude is determined by the maxima ( +/- 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me break it down for you:

This struct defines "state" that is used to control the generated signal. `left_phase` is used to store the next sample value for the left channel. `right_phase` stores the next value for the right channel.

```
typedef struct
{
    float left_phase;
    float right_phase;
}   
paTestData;
```

This is the callback function registered with PortAudio. PortAudio passes data from the input stream (microphone) to `inputBuffer` for processing by the user. The user passes data to `outputBuffer` that is sent to the sound card's output stream (speakers). `userData` is some value or struct passed when the callback is registered. In this case it is an instance of `paTestData`.

```
/* This routine will be called by the PortAudio engine when audio is needed.
** It may called at interrupt level on some machines so don't do anything
** that could mess up the system like calling malloc() or free().
*/ 
static int patestCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                           unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                           const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                           PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                           void *userData )
{
    /* Cast data passed through stream to our structure. */
    paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData; 
    float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;
    unsigned int i;
    (void) inputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warning. */
```

This for loop is where the signal is generated, one frame at a time. `framesPerBuffer` (determined in part by the user when the callback is registered and in part by the OS) controls how many samples are generated. Each iteration of the loop generates two samples of audio data. For a stereo stream the samples are interleaved. The first sample goes to the left channel. The second sample goes to the right channel.

```
    for( i=0; i<framesPerBuffer; i++ )
    {
        *out++ = data->left_phase;  /* left */
        *out++ = data->right_phase;  /* right */

        /* Generate simple sawtooth phaser that ranges between -1.0 and 1.0. */
        data->left_phase += 0.01f;
        /* When signal reaches top, drop back down. */
        if( data->left_phase >= 1.0f ) data->left_phase -= 2.0f;

        /* higher pitch so we can distinguish left and right. */
        data->right_phase += 0.03f;
        if( data->right_phase >= 1.0f ) data->right_phase -= 2.0f;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code from the for loop controls frequency and amplitude (volume). Each sample represents the amplitude of the signal for that slice of time (determined by sample rate). In this case frequency is determined by the values `0.01f` and `0.03f`. Amplitude is determined by `if( data->left_phase >= 1.0f ) data->left_phase -= 2.0f;` for the left channel and `if( data->right_phase >= 1.0f ) data->right_phase -= 2.0f;` for the right channel.

```
data->left_phase += 0.01f;
/* When signal reaches top, drop back down. */
if( data->left_phase >= 1.0f ) data->left_phase -= 2.0f;

/* higher pitch so we can distinguish left and right. */
data->right_phase += 0.03f;
if( data->right_phase >= 1.0f ) data->right_phase -= 2.0f;
```

As the description says in the code comment, the for loop generates a type of periodic function called a [sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave). The frequency is determined by the distance between the "teeth." If there are 1000 teeth per second of signal, a 1000 Hz tone is generated.The amplitude is determined by how tall the teeth are. If the peak-to-peak distance (bottom to top) is -1 to 1, that is an amplitude of 1 (100% for floating point samples). That is also 0 db, or unity gain. You can calculate db from the signal amplitude using equations defined [in this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel). (See Acoustics.) A good exercise would be to generate a different waveform, like a [square wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave), [triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave), and [sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave). They will each generate pitches with unique characteristics.

In the code, the left phase increases in amplitude 0.01 each sample and from -1 to 1 in 200 samples. The frequency is determined by the relationship between this waveform and the sample rate of the audio stream. If the sample rate is 48 kHz, then each sample represents a slice of time 1/48000 seconds long. In this case, the signal frequency is 240 Hz (`48000 / 200`)

To understand this all better, you might put this algorithm into a spreadsheet and plot the points, or even better, into python and use a plotting library to visualize the wave. You could also work it out on paper. The x-values are time, and the y-values are amplitude. I also suggest you read up on [pulse-code modulation (PCM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation). `inputBuffer` and `outputBuffer` are buffers (arrays) of PCM data. It is also the encoding used in WAV files.

Comment: first of all thank you, I finally started understanding what is happening, but what do these numbers equal to, like for example, if maxima is +/- 1 (`if( data->left_phase >= 1.0f ) data->left_phase -= 2.0f`), how many db is that? or 0.01f (`data->left_phase += 0.01f`) equals to how many Hz?

Comment: I updated my answer to provide more details. The best thing you can do is research the topics I linked and work the algorithm out by hand, or with a spreadsheet.